# In itunesConnect my app showing Apple Pay option and I am using Braintree. how to get rid of showing Apple Pay option in my itunesConnect?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, braintree, applepay

My iTunesConnect app showing Apple Pay option. I am using Braintree.

**Even we are not using the Apple Pay feature in the app.**

Any one can help me out how to get rid of showing Apple Pay option in my itunesConnect?

I am using pod for Braintree

pod 'Braintree', '~> 4.9.6'

Answer (score 0):

We encourage you to update the version of the pod you are using. The [latest version](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) is 4.20.2. If this doesn't resolve your issue, please contact [Support](https://help.braintreepayments.com/) for further troubleshooting specific to your gateway and integration.

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [Support](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>